# Web Scraping NBA Fantasy Projections - R

Tags: r, rvest

There are a number of NBA Fantasy Projections that I would like to scrape in a more streamlined approach. Currently I use a combination of importhtml function in google sheets and simple archaic cut'n'paste.

I use R regularly to scrape other data from the internet, however, I can't manage to get these tables to scrape. The tables I am having trouble with are located at three separate addresses (1 table per page), they are:

1) http://www.sportsline.com/nba/player-projections/player-stats/all-players/

2) https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections

3) http://www.sportingcharts.com/nba/dfs-projections/

For all my other scraping activities I use packages rvest and xml. Following the same process I've tried both methods listed below which result in the outputs shown. I'm sure this has something to do with the format of the table on the website, however I haven't been able to find something that can help me.

---

**Method 1**

```
library(XML)
projections1 <- readHTMLTable("http://www.sportsline.com/nba/player-projections/player-stats/all-players/")
projections2 <- readHTMLTable("https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections")
projections3 <- readHTMLTable("http://www.sportingcharts.com/nba/dfs-projections/")
```

*Output*

```
projections1    
named list()

projections2
named list()
Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections'
```

projections3 - I get the headers of the table but not the content of the table.

**Method 2**

```
library(rvest)
URL <- "http://www.sportsline.com/nba/player-projections/player-stats/all-players/"
projections1 <- URL %>%  
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes("table")  %>% 
    html_table(trim=TRUE,fill=TRUE)

URL <- "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections"
projections2 <- URL %>%  
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes("table")  %>% 
    html_table(trim=TRUE,fill=TRUE)

URL <- "http://www.sportingcharts.com/nba/dfs-projections/"
projections3 <- URL %>%  
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes("table")  %>% 
    html_table(trim=TRUE,fill=TRUE)
```

*Output*

```
projections1    
list()
```

projections2 - I get the headers of the table but not the content of the table.

projections3 - I get the headers of the table but not the content of the table.

---

If anybody could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the content of the table is generated by javascript, so `readHTMLTable` and `read_html` find nothing, you can find the table as below

projections1: [link](http://www.sportsline.com/sportsline-web/service/v1/playerProjections?league=nba&position=all-players&sourceType=FD&game=&page=PS&offset=0&max=25&orderField=&optimal=false&release2Ver=true&auth=3)

```
import requests 
url = 'http://www.sportsline.com/sportsline-web/service/v1/playerProjections?league=nba&position=all-players&sourceType=FD&game=&page=PS&offset=0&max=25&orderField=&optimal=false&release2Ver=true&auth=3'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.json()
```

projections2: view-source:https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections  Line 1181

```
import requests   
url = 'https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections'
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.content
print eval(text.split('this.players = ')[1].split(';')[0])
```

projections3: view-source Line 918

Comment: Wow, now that is cool. I honestly didn't know about view source before.

Comment: Although, I have no idea how to scrape from a website source, could you give me some direction on how to do this?